# What are the pros and cons to have a seperate project devoted to unit-tests only?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, msbuild, tdd, nunit

Can you compare the advantages and disadvantages of having all your unit tests in one project devoted to unit-tests only against having your unit-tests residing the relevant assemblies?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Advantages to keeping them in seperate assemblies:

- doesn't unnecessarily increase the complexity of the module being tested and doesn't violate separation of concerns.
- you won't need to have your testing framework referenced throughout your solution.
- it will enable (or at least make it easier for you) you to set up your project in a CI environment.

Comment: Another benefit is that you really get to see how clients of your API/library will use your code since you are referencing the project/dll you are testing.  Also keeping references to dlls you use for testing(unit test libraries, mock libraries, etc) out of your main assemblies will keep their output smaller and prevent someone from actually using those for non testing purposes out of confusion.

Answer (score 3):

For myself, there are 2 immediate pros.

The first is that, when I ship the bits, I'm shipping only code that is used for the application in question.

The other benefit is in a continuous integration (CI) environment, I can point my unit testing framework to a list of assemblies that match a pre-defined name pattern, such as any assemblies that end in "Test".

Answer (score 2):

The main pro is [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Classes and tests for them are completely orthogonal and should be separated. Other pros and cons can really be derived from it, for example user needs application, but you will have to ship application + tests, because they are spiked.

Answer (score 0):

The major drawback when including unit tests directly next to the code they're testing is that an additional mechanism becomes required to exclude the test code from the delivered binaries.

The only problem I can think of when isolating unit tests in a separated project is that, depending on the language you're using, it may become difficult to test purely internal classes. For a current C++ project, I'm using a separated project with a specific 'Unit tests' build configuration in which my product builds as a static library instead of a dll, thus allowing the test project to access any type or function regardless of its export specifications.

Comment: I think if you are working in .Net framework, to let your internal types reachable specifically from your project that resides unit-tests you may make use of InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Comment: @burak: I didn't know such thing existed in .Net, nice to know !

Answer (score 0):

**Specific to C#:**

Note that a class and its tests are tightly coupled. Separating in to two assemblies stretches that coupling link across assembly boundaries.

I prefer to put my unit tests in the same assembly as the class they're testing.  For each class `C` in namespace `N` I will put unit tests in class `CTests` in namespace `N.Tests`.

It's trivial to tests non-public classes. (A common refrain in TDD is that you shouldn't be unit testing private members; I agree. Here I'm talking about `internal` classes and `internal` members.)

I don't have to juggle as many assemblies.

I should add that I don't mind shipping my unit tests to my users. It would be different if they were downloading over dialup, or running on systems with minimal storage.

**Aside:**

If I could, I would put my unit tests in a nested class, like this:

```
public class C
{
    // note 'private' accessibility. 
    [TestFixture]
    class Tests
    {
        // tests here
    }

    // Implementation of C here
}
```

Some advantages:

- Renaming `C` doesn't require renaming `CTests`.
- I know exactly where to find my tests.
- A test and the code under test are always together.

This only works if your classes are small. Once they get big, the file becomes enormous. It's possible to use `partial` classes to put them in separate files.

Unfortunately, NUnit and Visual Studio's unit testing framework don't see non-public test fixtures. I don't believe there's an advantage to excluding non-public tests, but that's how they work.